# Динамическая матрица

Tags: c++, массивы

Как лучше хранить динамическую матрицу: `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, `std::vector<std::vector<T>*>` или `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>>`, где `T - a) trivial type; b) non-trivial type`?

Comment: 1 - Хранить значения объектов, как правило, проще чем указатели на них. 2 - хранить нетривиальные типы нужно в любом случае по указателю. 3 - хранить умные указатели(`std::unique_ptr`), как правило, проще чем обычные указатели.

Comment: Ну это для "сферичесокой матрицы в вакууме":)  На практике всегда есть всякие "но"

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb просто везде используют первый вариант, где смотрел; но ведь даже вектор векторов тривиальных типов хранить накладно?

Comment: сам лично не заметил разницы между указателями и vector<vector<map>> и другими при работе с внутренним vector<T>

Comment: @qwerty Не так уж и накладно. Например, в VC++ накладные расходы памяти вектора составляют порядка 12 байт - независимо от количества элементов. Если вы работаете с указателями - что изменится? По **лишнему** указателю для каждого вектора во втором измерении + лишняя косвенность при обращении.

Comment: @qwerty, Хотя знаете, на счет нетривиальных типов я погорячился. Их можно хранить и по значению. Все зависит от того, что вы собираетесь с ними делать.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, как говорится, depends on... 
Лично я бы из приведенных вариантов предпочел первый - в силу простоты работы, естественного обращения к элементам через две операции индексации, отсутствия накладных расходов на косвенные обращения.

Но, вполне возможно, использовал бы какой-то иной (возможно, собственный) вариант - если бы была какая-то информация о матрице - какие операции планируются, плотная/разреженная, насколько важна эффективность при работе, насколько часто будут (и будут ли) меняться размеры матрицы...

Answer (score 1):

> Как лучше хранить динамическую матрицу

Матрица любой размерности неплохо отображается в одномерный вектор. Ваша задача сведется к тому, чтобы только играться с индексами.